# which fraction of the solar radiation corresponds the blocked part by Venus at its transit upon he sun?

Tags: the-sun, radiation, planetary-transits

Well, asumming that Venus orbits the Sun at 0.7233 AU and its diameter is 12,104 km, I can conclude that its angular diameter seen from the earth is ~1', then its represents ~1/31 part of the angular diameter of solar disc, so that's represents only $1365Wm^{-2}/31 ~ 44 Wm^{-2}$ , hence that fraction represents just ~ 44/1365 ~ 0.0322... of the total radiation.

Did I reason correctly?

Comment: I think you have wrongly compared the ratios of the angular diameters, rather than the ratio of the area of the disks? So calculate ratio of pi*(angular radius)^2 for Venus/Sun... would give you a much smaller fraction.

Comment: @lucas Ohhhh I get it, I get it, I passed off the fact that I was looking for the area of the disks